How much resources do I need to develop my own GPT?
I have an idea for a GPT.  While ideally I can use something like ChatGPT or ClaudeGPT or something else, I want to my GPT to have a specific tone when providing responses.  This part is very important.
Would it make more sense to use a prebuilt GPT and somehow get it to respond in the right way?  OR, do I have to create my GPT from scratch?
Hence, I'm wondering how difficult/resources it would take for me to develop my GPT?  To see if it's a viable option.

I'd suggest you to go for prompt engineering over finetuning...

Prompt engineering, but I would still be using something already pre-made like ChatGPT?  I want ChatGPT to assume a specific 'personality' and not break said personality no matter what the user does.

There is no product or software called ClaudeGPT. The term GPT is really only used for OpenAI's product. It might help if you removed the term GPT from the question, and described what you wanted to make, including your comment about a robust personality.

You might also find the https://genai.stackexchange.com/ site is more specific to your question, provided your strategy is to use some existing service as a starting point

Well my question is should I use an existing service or think of a way to create my own?  But I will check it out.  I'm looking for something very similar to ChatGPT, but more tailored for my specific use case - basically I give it the personality I want and also the knowledge that I want in a particular niche area.
